# How to include shell command in shell_exec function?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to overwrite a `.txt file` in a remote server using PHP. The Linux command that I have used is working fine when it is in bash script. But with `shell_exec()` it is not working.

Here is the command:

```
$number = $_GET["phone"];   
$out = shell_exec("echo $number | ssh root@0.0.0.0 '"cat > /path/to/file/number.txt"'");
echo $out;
```

Note that the keys between two servers are already shared. So the ssh command works without asking for passwords.

Comment: Try double quotes in single quotes: `shell_exec('echo ..."cat..."')`

Comment: Does this code actually run? Please include any errors or output it produces.

Comment: This works for simple shell commands like `shell_exec(pwd);` But for the above command it is not working and no any error displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can use backtick operator that will substitute the shell command.

```
out = shell_exec('ls -alrt')
echo "$out"
```

shell_exec() it returns all of its output stream as string.

---

Problem is you don't close the quote at the right place that is causing the problem.

An example script and get some inspiration on changing the quotes on your command.

```
$page = shell_exec("/tmp/script.sh '".$my_url."'");
```

Comment: Still it's not works. `shell_exec("echo $number")` works fine. But `shell_exec("echo $number > /a.txt")` also not works.

Comment: why `shell_exec("echo $number > /a.txt")` is not working?

Comment: @PiyumiGuruge, what error you get when you run the above command?

Comment: Nothing. when the value is submitted, it just redirect to blank page. But no any .txt file created in the given location. `shell_exec("echo $number")` gives the number displayed instead of the blank page in browser.

Comment: `<?php
        if(isset($_GET['phone'])) {
              $number = $_GET["phone"];
//$out = "echo $number | ssh root@0.0.0.0 "cat > /path/to/file/number_bkp.txt"";
 $out = shell_exec("echo $number > /number_bkp.txt"); 
        echo "$out";
        }
?>
`

Comment: Why  `/` in front of the file name?

Comment: its root. The file location.

Comment: Here is the complete problem that i'm having. There are two servers and keys are already shared. One has the text file which should be updated. Other one has the web page hosted to add the value by user via form submission.